# Eclipse android configuration issue

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've been setting up my `Android SDK` and `ADT Plugin` in Eclipse this morning and my first couple of tests when building an android app have worked fine.

However now I'm starting to get a pop-up everytime I click on something saying `AN ERROR HAS OCCURED - JAVA.NULLPOINTER.EXCEPTION`.

I understand a nullpointer exception in Java is when something has been created but I haven't even typed in any code yet its just a standard mainactivity class created by the app creation wizard when you click new project.

The problems started when I ran the program and it seemed to have had an issue with `Activity_mainlayout.out.xml` or whatever its called.

Anyone got any ideas as to why this happening it was working before and I haven't begun to code my application.

Few details:
Eclipse using the Android ADT Plugin and Android SDK with an Android Virtual Device for testing.

Thanks guys.

P.s. I deleted the project in windows explorer and in Eclipse so got rid of it completely and any new project now is producing the same pop-up error.

---

This is the code for MainActivity

```
package wag.cymal.libraryportal.welshlibraries;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.natlib); // background image
    this.setContentView(ll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And the activity_main XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Any ideas? :/

Comment: New development I've deleted some unused imports and I'm able to run my application in the Virtual Device but I'm still getting the pop-up box all the time.

Comment: Could it be that your calling a `View` (e.g. `TextView`, `Button`, etc) on your code which is not declared on your layout?

Comment: Not sure as I've said I haven't modified any code except adding a background image.

Comment: The error "AN ERROR HAS OCCURED - JAVA.NULLPOINTER.EXCEPTION'." - where is it being shown? In logcat, console or as an eclipse popup?

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with the API you are working on. My suggestion is to delete the API package and then install it again. Might work. Or you may try to run it with some other API.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sctivity_mainlayout.out.xml' is created when you try to run the aplication while you are in an xml file. As far I understand, the compiler tries to compile the xml file, and this generates the .out.xml file, which is not valid xml, and this causes an error.

Solution: delete the .out.xml file, and always when you run watch out that the editor has focus in java file (or none)...

Now if for some reason your eclipse is messed up, try running it with the option  --clean (using the command line, or in the case of Windows, also "execute" option -> "`c:\mypathtoeclipse\eclipse.exe --clean`"). This makes eclipse itself to be rebuilt. In my case it has fixed several times some unexplainable, unexpected exceptions I got during workspace load.

Comment: Thank you for this, the focus was on the main XML file and not the Java file so that was fine. However everything I click on still comes up with this silly pop up box. Considering turning it off and on again

Comment: No, what I mean, is that when you try to run having focus on an XML file, it will generate .out XML file and that's wrong. The second thing - it's an error of eclipse, right? Then try running eclipse with the --clean option as I posted.

Comment: HA! I restarted Eclipse and all is well no more pop up box but thank you for your help on focusing on the java file.

Comment: Just to clarify yes I understand about the out. XML file being generated if I ran the XML file. Thank you for your help.